# Play Framework Application and embedded Database packaging

Tags: mongodb, playframework, packaging, embedded-database, sbt-native-packager

I implemented a server application with Play Framework.
I built native packages for different Operating Systems (Linux, Windows, Mac OS X) with [SBT Native Packager](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/).
This application requires a NoSQL Database. In particular, I am using MongoDB. Is there a way to embed MongoDB binary/package in my native package? Is this the best practice? Or do you suggest to install MongoDB and my Play application with two different packages?
If it is not possible / recommended to embed MongoDB in a package, do you suggest another DBMS (for instance [Nitrite Database](https://github.com/dizitart/nitrite-database))? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really best practise. Play has H2 in-memory DB embedded but this is only intended for development (because it is quicker than something that reads/writes to disk as well).

You really want to have your Mongo (or whatever other data store you decide to use) instance running in a different process, and packaged, deployed, stopped, started separately from your Play application.

You could probably figure out how to package it with your Play application and then have some script run during app startup to setup the database and load any existing data in `-dbpath` ie. whenever you redeploy/restart your application. But then you would have to stop/redeploy your Mongo binaries each time you redeploy a code change. You may update your application several times over a year but you are unlikely going to want to update your Mongo binaries as often. I could go on, but don't do it. It is best practise to manage your data stores separately from your applications.